# Does not Show markers depending on Node ID via Openlayers

Tags: javascript

I have a problem in OpenLayers Map.The name of the URL path is localhost/restaurant-dp/?q=view_map/1 , I pass node id to Open Layers Map view, I got Map ,But doesn't show markers with Map.

List of following setting done my view.

```
  Format: OpenLayers Map | Settings
    -  click settings then Map :OpenLayers Locator Node Map   

 Contextual filters :  Content: Nid  -> Provide default value : Content ID from URl
```

[image]

Here, What did I do Wrong ?

Comment: Could you post the export code  of you view? That would help a lot

Comment: You have to create a openmap layer for that after that attach this layer on map.

Comment: You may find the article: [Building Maps with OpenLayers in Drupal 7](http://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/building-maps-openlayers-drupal-7) useful.